# How to toggle between LTE and Wifi through mobile Automation

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-ios

Is it possible to write automation to simulate network toggle between LTE and Wifi while user is performing an action on an iOS mobile app?

Appium supports only Android but not iOS.
https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/network_connection.md

Answer (score 0):

```
public void network(boolean airplaneMode, boolean wifi, boolean mobileData){

NetworkConnectionSetting networkConnection = new NetworkConnectionSetting(airplaneMode, wifi, mobileData); 
((AndroidDriver<?>) driver).setNetworkConnection(networkConnection); 
 }
```

Set true/ false to enable or disable network.